# get element in div by eq()

Tags: jquery, html

I have a few pictures in an `#img_wrapper` which all are wrapped in a link:

```
<div id="img_wrapper">
  <a href="img1.jpg" style="display: none;">
   <img src="img1.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="img2.jpg" style="display: none;">
   <img src="img2.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="img3.jpg" style="display: none;">
   <img src="img3.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="img4.jpg" style="display: none;">
   <img src="img4.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="img5.jpg" style="display: none;">
   <img src="img5.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="img6.jpg" style="display: none;">
   <img src="img6.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

and I try to grab specific links by `.eq()`

```
var f = 2;
$('#img_wrapper').eq(f).fadeIn();
```

problem is, that does not work. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

You're targeting the container. You need to instead select the links within it:

```
var f = 2;
$('#img_wrapper a').eq(f).fadeIn();
```

Comment: yes sure, I wasn't clear about that index counts on the elements itself, not on the parent! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
$('#img_wrapper').find('a').eq(f).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var f = 2;
$('#img_wrapper a').eq(f).fadeIn();
```